# Is there a way to get the coverage information collected by jest during the test execution?

Tags: jestjs, test-coverage

I want to create some kind of fuzz test with jest. For this I've created a loop within a test definition (it).

As a break condition I want to use a time limit and an achieved coverage count.
Unfortunately jest generates the coverage report at the end of the test execution.

Is there a way to export/access the coverage.json during the test run?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet of the code you're talking about? Which approaches did you try to solve your problem?